# Making Midi Files in Python that are Polyphonic and Different Instruments

Tags: python, midi, synthesis

I'm looking for a midi library in Python that will allow me to create a polyphonic midi file using different instruments.

What seems to get recommended here alot is [MidiUtil](http://code.google.com/p/midiutil/). Although, it seems to have support for polyphony, I can't seem to change the instrument from piano.

Can anyone recommend an alternative midi library or advise on how to change the instrument?

Comment: I suppose this is not the place for this question... anyway, I am almost sure a way to a add a program change (the way you change the instrument for a midi track) must exist, and in fact read http://www.emergentmusics.org/mididutil-class-reference , addProgramChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, each of the different timbres that you'd like to use in your file need to have their events on a separate MIDI channel. Before any notes sound on each channel, use the `addProgramChange()`method of the MIDIFIle object to select the correct patch on each channel.

addProgramChange(track, channel, time, program)

#### Add a MIDI program change event.

Use `MyMIDI.addProgramChange(track,channel, time, program)`

#### Arguments

**track:** The track to which the event is added. [Integer, 0-127].
**channel:** The channel the event is assigned to. [Integer, 0-15].
**time:** The time at which the event is added, in beats. [Float].
**program:** the program number. [Integer, 0-127].

See http://www.emergentmusics.org/mididutil-class-reference for documentation of all the methods supported by that class.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that instruments were called programs according to the MIDI specification, my bad.